# Backslash in string gives ¥ instead of a backslash

Tags: backslash

I'm trying to print a simple string in Python something like

```
print("Finding\nNemo")
```

And im trying to learn how to use the "escape" backslash but when I print the string in python it gives me this symbol here ¥ instead of a backslash and I cant figure out why it shows that in python and not a proper backslash.

Comment: What terminal are you using? What's the output you're getting? What's the output you're receiving?

Comment: just a fore-warning i am extremely new to python so im not sure what you mean by the outputs im getting or receiving. Also i think the terminal is                         C:¥Users¥USAFH¥PycharmProjects¥Giraffe

Comment: The terminal you're using would be something like "cmd.exe" or etc

Comment: What Windows locale are you in?

Comment: yup i had the wrong system locale on, perfect thanks for your help!